# How can i add data-title with jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<td data-title="Company">AUSTRALIAN AGRICULTURAL COMPANY LIMITED.</td>
```

I'm using datatable with ajax how can i add data-title when table loading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

or `attr()`

```
$("td").attr("data-title","some title");
```

Answer (score 4):

use `.data()`:

```
$('td').data('title','some title');
```

Comment: $('#dataTable').find('tbody').find('td:eq(1)').data('title','Ad');

This usage wrong ? did not work like this

Comment: can you share the DOM or fiddle

Comment: Should be noted this won't add the data-title attribute so if e.g some CSS rules depend of this attribute, this won't have any effect

Comment: i believe OP needs to use .attr in that case

Comment: @MilindAnantwar correct but as no one know it except OP and using data object is generally preferred method +1 anyway

Comment: $('#dataTable').find('tbody').find('td:eq(1)').attr("data-title","Ad"); This one work